# Creating parcelable class

Tags: java, android

my class looks like this when I run my application and navigate throug the different  fragments  sometimes it crashes and logcat says that error is BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class ge.mobility.weather.entity.City

here is my code

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class City implements Parcelable {
    private String code;
    private String name;

    private List<CityWeather> weathers ;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public List<CityWeather> getWeathers() {
        if(weathers == null) {
            weathers = new ArrayList<CityWeather>();
        }
        return weathers;
    }
    public void addCityWeather(CityWeather w) {
        getWeathers().add(w);
    }

    public void addCityWeathers(List<CityWeather> w) {
        getWeathers().addAll(w);
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {enter code here
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub`enter code here`

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the Parcelable.Creator and also add the un/serialise methods and a constructor:

```
public City(Parcel in) {
    readFromParcel(in);
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(code);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeTypedList(weathers);
}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    code = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    in.readTypedList(weathers, CityWeather.CREATOR);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<City> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<City>() {
    public City createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new City(in);
    }

    public City[] newArray(int size) {
        return new City[size];
    }
};
```

You will also need to implement the Parcelable methods for the `CityWeather` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code generation library [Parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) , if you are use InteliJ Use this plugin  [IntelliJ Plugin for Android Parcelable boilerplate code generation](https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin)